# Need to create multiple line in body of the mail using outlook

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I need to create 2 or more seperate lines in the body of the mail and a Hi with the there name to be added before the body of the mail in the below code... I am trying to send bulk mail to the customer.Need help in resolving this at the earliest.

```
Sub Send_email_fromexcel()
Dim edress As String
Dim subj As String
Dim message As String
Dim filename As String
Dim outlookapp As Object
Dim outlookmailitem As Object
Dim myAttachments As Object
Dim path As String
Dim lastrow As Integer
Dim attachment As String
Dim x As Integer

 x = 2

Do While Sheet1.Cells(x, 1) <> ""
   
    Set outlookapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set outlookmailitem = outlookapp.createitem(0)
    Set myAttachments = outlookmailitem.Attachments
    path = ""
    edress = Sheet1.Cells(x, 1)
      
    subj = Sheet1.Cells(x, 2)
    filename = Sheet1.Cells(x, 3)
    attachment = path + filename


    
        outlookmailitem.To = edress
        outlookmailitem.cc = ""
        outlookmailitem.bcc = ""
        outlookmailitem.Subject = subj
        
        **' Need Help here  '
        outlookmailitem.body = "Please find your statement attached,& vbcrLf & Kindly check the list and confirm"**
        
           
            
        myAttachments.Add (attachment)
        outlookmailitem.display
        'outlookmailitem.send
            
        lastrow = lastrow + 1
        edress = ""
    x = x + 1

Loop


Set outlookapp = Nothing
Set outlookmailitem = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your line needs to insert the name separated by "&" to concatenate.

It looks like you had the right idea but need to keep the "&" outside the double quotes.

Assuming `custname` is the variable holding Customer's Name, the line should look like:

```
outlookmailitem.body = "Please find your statement attached," & custname & vbcrLf  & "Kindly check the list and confirm"
```